# Best Practices - set jQuery property from Code-Behind

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I need to set a single property in a jQuery command using a value that is calculated in the code-behind. My initial thought was to just use `<%= %>` to access it like this:

.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$('.sparklines').sparkline('html', {
    fillColor: 'transparent',
    normalRangeMin: '0',
    normalRangeMax: <%= NormalRangeMax() %>
});
</script>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected string NormalRangeMax() {
    // Calculate the value.
}
```

It smells odd to have to call from the ASPX page to just get a single value though. Not to mention I have an entire method that does a small calculation just to populate a single property.

One alternative would be to create the entire `<script>` block in the code-behind using `clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. But I really don't like putting entire chunks of JavaScript in the code-behind since its, well, JavaScript.

Maybe if I end up having many of these methods I can just put then in a partial class so at least they are physically separate from the rest of the code.

What method would you recommend as being easy to understand and easy to maintain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <% %> works fine. One thing that I do is set a value in a hidden field on the page (then writing the necessary javascript to extract that value), this is nice because I can change that hidden field via javascript and when/if the page posts back I can get that new value from code behind as well.

If you need to call the method on demand, you could do an jQuery AJAX call to a ASP.NET WebMethod to grab the data and re-populate the various options. You can find a good tutorial on how to do that here: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Below is some sample code using the hidden field method (using the datepicker control, but you'll get the idea):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalendar" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTest" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/ui.datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dateMinimum = new Date($("#<%= hfTest.ClientID %>").val());

    $(function() {
        $("#<%= txtCalendar.ClientID %>")
            .datepicker({
                minDate: dateMinimum
            });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

And the code behind Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set Value of Hidden Field to the first day of the current month.
    this.hfTest.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use the <% %> method. This is what the view is for. I don't like the RegisterClientScriptBlock at all. If you ever move to MVC you will get used to the <% %> ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a while back.  I recommend <% %> for single variable stuff.  I find the RegisterClientScriptBlock function useful only if I ever need the code-behind to determine which scripts to run.

Answer (score 0):

Rick has a nice [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/259442.aspx) about passing server vars to client script