# Setting JQuery property from codebehind not triggering

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do what is in this question [Best Practices - set jQuery property from Code-Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471820/best-practices-set-jquery-property-from-code-behind)

My page has this code:

```
function Initialize() {
    $("#txtFromDateF").datepicker();
    $(".needs-datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: $("#<%= minDays . ClientID %>").val()
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    Session.ResetTimer();
    Initialize();

});
```

on my page I have a hiddenfield :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="minDays" runat="server" Value="" />
```

in my codebehind On Page_load :

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    ' Do some stuff
End If

SetMinDays()
```

The SetMinDays() looks as follows:

```
Private Sub SetMinDays()
    Select Case TicketSubTypeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeFrequency
            minDays.Value = "+10d"
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeOpeningHours
            minDays.Value = "+30d"
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeCiNumber
            minDays.Value = "+20d"
        Case Else
            minDays.Value = "+0d"
    End Select
End Sub
```

When i select a differnet TicketSubType in the dropdown, I pass through the SetMinDays(). But my screen doesn't update the datepicker.

How can I make sure the datepicker uses the value that is assigned in the SetMinDays ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but are a lot of things to take care of, let not mumble here for nothing, if this hidden field isn't repeating in the page (embedded control) do this small hack:

if you are using asp.net 4.0 or higher, make client id static:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="minDays" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" />
```

read like this:

```
minDate: $("#minDays").val()
```

**Update:**

In .aspx file read server id:

```
<script>
   var yourid= '<%= minDays.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

In external js file use like this:

```
minDate: $("#" + yourid).val();
```

Comment: I'm using an older version. So I don't have the ClientIDMode.

Comment: Then read the id in page (extremely important to use server tags in page not external script files), use auxiliary variable at page load get the id, use that for initialization

Comment: i don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: in console alert(yourid);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84987/discussion-between-silenttremor-and-bart-schelkens).